# TCP communication with client behind NAT

Tags: visual-c++, boost-asio, tcpclient, nat

Is it possible for server to send a message to client behind NAT which initiated the connection? I'm making distributed application in c++ using Boost.Asio library. Do i have to enable some specific parameter to force client to check whether there is a message for it on the server node?

Comment: How else would anything behind a NAT work otherwise? Think of someone behind a NAT browsing the web, the web uses HTTP which is a protocol built on top of TCP, and the broswer communicates with a server on the other side of the NAT. In short, yes it's possible for a server program to communicate to a connected TCP client.

Comment: But i didnt mean immediate response but delayed. E.g. Client initiated connection. Nothing happens for 5 minutes and suddenly server sends a message to client.

Comment: If the connection is established then the NAT has it recorded, so it knows who should receive the packet from the server. The term NAT stands for Network Address ***Translation***, it's that *translation* part is the keyword here, the device handling the NAT keep track of all TCP connections through the NAT device, you could say it works like a proxy: All packets sent on a connection are simply forwarded to the actual device on the other end, no matter the direction.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks, i think its clear now